# PHP and prevent uasort function from sorting if values are equivalent

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm using an array with PHP's uasort function. If `$a[0]['date'] == $b[0]['date']`, then I do not want to sort.

Anyway, my code will sort anyway. How could I prevent it from doing so?

Here is my array:

And here is the array:

```
Array (
  [2764] => Array (
    [status] => 0

    [0] => Array (
      [date] => 2000-01-01
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [date] => 2016-01-16
    )
  )

  [5974] => Array (
    [status] => 0

    [0] => Array (
      [date] => 2000-01-01
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [date] => 2010-12-13
    )
  )
)
```

And here is how I'm trying to sort:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b)
{
  if ($a['status'] == $b['status'])
  {
    if ($a[0]['date'] == $b[0]['date'])
    {
      return 0; # I do not want to sort here, but this will sort anyway - why is that so?
    }
    else
    {
      return strcmp($a[0]['date'], $b[0]['date']);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    return $b['status'] - $a['status'];
  }
});
```

How could I sort by indexes if dates are same? I mean sorting by indexes 2764 and 5974.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.
```

So you have to introduce extra value, such as `original_order` and sort by it equal entries.

Comment: How could I sort by indexes if dates are same? I mean sorting by indexes 2764 and 5974.

Comment: You can only try to use something like this: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.asort.php#80798

Comment: I added a new key/value pair to my array. Now the array can be sorted by original order numbers if dates are same. Thanks for your help, kuba.